# browser.actions() without a perform()

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Recently, I've noticed that one of our tests has the following line:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.RETURN);
```

The intent is understandable, but *it would actually do nothing* since `perform()` was not called. For some reason, the test itself was passing which indicates a problem in the logic of the test and the following expectations.

How can I spot this kind of problems as early as possible and, ideally, prevent this protractor/WebDriverJS usage violation to be committed into the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use *static code analysis* - there is an `ESLint` linting utility that has a set of different plugins. Nowadays, there is a [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) that, aside from other protractor-specific violations, would catch [`browser.actions()` without `perform()`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-perform.md).

Here is the output of a `ESLint` run in this case:

```
/Users/user/job/app/specs/test.spec.js
36:13  error    No perform() called on browser.actions()        protractor/missing-perform
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect this could be achieved via a (scriptable) editor plugin or linter rule.

That said, surely the best way to evaluate the test script is to run it for real - but also to ensure that all test actions have a corresponding assertion / validation.

Your `Key.RETURN` must presumably have some effect on the DOM, or initiate some action, the result of which can be detected (page changes, data changes, etc.) and which is probably meaningful and easier to read than a static analysis rule.